# Testing composition example from the main method

Tags: c#

I was learning composition and wrote this car class.
I am not using any IOC container at the moment. I just want to be able to test this Car class
from my main method.

How can I test this because I can't instantiate Car any more. It comes with an error.

```
public class Car
{
    private readonly IRadio _objRadio;
    public Car(IRadio objRadio)
    {
        _objRadio = objRadio;
    }
    //private Radio myRadio = new Radio();
    public void TurnOnRadio(bool onOff)
    {
        _objRadio.Power(onOff);
    }
}

 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car viper = new Car();
        viper.TurnOnRadio(false);
    }
```

Comment: `Car viper = new Car(new Radio());`

Answer (score 0):

> I can't instantiate Car any more. It comes with an error.

Because your `Car` class now requires an `IRadio` instance in its constructor. If you have a class that implements `IRadio` you could pass in an instance of that class:

```
Car viper = new Car(new Radio());
```